# DateTime How To

Tags: c#

When creating a class what is the syntax to define a public property for that class as a DateTime type rather than string?

Comment: public DateTime DateFiled { get; set; }

works but how do i format it? in the set or get method?

Comment: well I have this being bound to a gridview and I want to format it so that only the date shows in US format

Comment: What type of GridView? Is it in a Windows Forms Application, WPF, ASP.NET Web Forms?

Comment: Actually I should provide some more info on what I am doing as it may not be as straight forward. I am using Linq to SQL and executing a custom query. You can see my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806243/using-custom-sql-queries-with-linq-to-sql-help

The custom class has the datetime property. In my UI code I am just handing it off to the grid like so...

MerchantsAppDataContext dc = new MerchantsAppDataContext();
var minDate = new DateTime(2008,1,1);
var submittals = dc.GetSubmittalDetails("1/1/2008");
GridView1.DataSource = submittals;
GridView1.DataBind();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

ASP.NET: BoundField's [DataFormatString property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) looks to be what you want.

```
<asp:BoundField 
       DataField="EventDate" 
       HeaderText="Event Date" 
       DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"/>
```

Easy as (pumpkin) pie. Happy Thanksgiving!

Comment: This works but now I have two date columns! The one I created by this code plus the one from my datacontext obj

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Is there a property on the gridview control to auto-generate columns? If so, you might have to turn that off and specify each column. There also might be a server-side event you can hook into to change the format of your column. (Sorry, I don't have much experience with that control.) Could you post a sample of your gridview's markup so we can see how it's declared? Thanks!

Comment: I set autoGenerateColumns to false and now can add my columns manually and format them on the fly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want a date object, with class-controlled formatting, you need two properties:

```
public DateTime DateField { get; set; }

// a read only string 
public String DateFieldString { 
    get { return DateField.ToString(/* your format */); } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
    public class TestClas
    {
        DateTime dtDate;

        public DateTime DtDate
        {
            get
            {
                return dtDate;
            }
            set
            {
                dtDate = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

and to get and set the field you can use

```
TestClas objDate = new TestClas();

// set date
objDate.DtDate = DateTime.Now;

// get date
DateTime dtCurDate = objDate.DtDate;
```

***Edit***

It would be better not to implement the formatting inside the property. Make the formatting inside the gridview. Otherwise if you need another formatting then you would have to create another property.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyClass {
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    public string MyFormattedDate { get { return MyDate.ToString(myFormat); } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;

public class Customer {

    private DateTime createDate;

    public DateTime CreateDate {
        get { return createDate; }
        set { createDate = value; }
    }

}
```